# CommunicationObjectAbortedException during reading large array from server

Tags: wcf, arrays

I'm receiving such exception during reading array of 40000 items.
Is there an idea why does it happen.
I've changed send/receive timeout to 30 min. Not helped.

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException was unhandled
>   by user code   Message=The socket connection has been disposed.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.ReadCore(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.DoneReceiving(Boolean
>   atEof, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.DoneReceiving(Boolean
>   atEof)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Close()
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.Close()
>          at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.Close()
>          at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.Close()
>          at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Close()
>          at System.Xml.XmlReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>          at System.Xml.XmlReader.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc&
>   rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at AlexSoft.Core.RemoteFacade.Contract.AdministrationSvc.IAdministrationRmService.GetAllBins()
>          at _dynamic_AlexSoft.Core.RemoteFacade.Contract.AdministrationSvc.IAdministrationRmService.GetAllBins(Object
>   , Object[] )
>          at Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeMethod.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments)
>          at Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicMethodInvocation.InvokeJoinpoint()
>          at Spring.Aop.Framework.AbstractMethodInvocation.Proceed()
>          at AlexSoft.Desktop.Services.RemoteFacade.ExtractRemoteExceptionAdvice.Invoke(IMethodInvocation
>   invocation) in
>   D:\proj\communic\trunk_fix_not_opened\src\SmartClient\Desktop.Services\RemoteFacade\ExtractRemoteExceptionAdvice.cs:line
>   15
>          at Spring.Aop.Framework.AbstractMethodInvocation.Proceed()
>          at Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicProxy.AdvisedProxy.Invoke(Object proxy, Object target, Type targetType, MethodInfo targetMethod,
>   MethodInfo proxyMethod, Object[] args, IList interceptors)
>          at CompositionAopProxy_8e3e641f50c44b68b5809af44bfae8bd.GetAllBins()
>          at AlexSoft.Desktop.Services.RemoteFacade.RemoteAdministrationService.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IAdministrationRmService
>   svc) in
>   D:\proj\communic\trunk_fix_not_opened\src\SmartClient\Desktop.Services\RemoteFacade\RemoteAdministrationService.cs:line
>   18
>          at AlexSoft.Desktop.Services.RemoteFacade.AbstractRemoteService`1.ExecuteRmAction(RmAction
>   action) in
>   D:\proj\communic\trunk_fix_not_opened\src\SmartClient\Desktop.Services\RemoteFacade\AbstractRemoteService.cs:line
>   121
>          at AlexSoft.Desktop.Services.RemoteFacade.RemoteAdministrationService.GetAllBins()
>   in
>   D:\proj\communic\trunk_fix_not_opened\src\SmartClient\Desktop.Services\RemoteFacade\RemoteAdministrationService.cs:line
>   24
>          at AlexSoft.MPObjects.Desktop.Controllers.UseCaseBinListController.ShowBinListView(IUseCaseBinListController
>   controller) in
>   D:\proj\communic\trunk_fix_not_opened\src\SmartClient\AlexSoft.MPObjects.Desktop\Controllers\UseCaseBinListController.cs:line
>   95
>          at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand`1.Execute(T
>   parameter)
>          at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand`1.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute(Object
>   parameter)
>          at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource
>   commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)   InnerException: System.IO.IOException
>          Message=The read operation failed, see inner exception.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>               at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>          InnerException: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException
>               Message=The socket connection has been disposed.
>               Source=System.ServiceModel
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ThrowIfNotOpen()
>                    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>                    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>                    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout)
>                    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>                    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>                    at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>                    at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>               InnerException: System.ObjectDisposedException
>                    Message=The socket connection has been disposed. Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection'.
>                    ObjectName=System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection
>                    InnerException:

Comment: This exception only hides real problem. It says that you tryed to access aborted connection. Try to turn on WCF tracing on client and server to get real exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to increase the maximum message sizes in the client and server configurations?
You can also have a look at the server to see if an exception has been logged.

The parameter named MaxSerializedObjectsInGraph may also reach its limit when serializing a lot of objects.

Comment: It seems the problem was in MaxSerializedObjectsInGraph and in <readerQuotas   maxArrayLength=

Comment: Make sure you set this in the server and client side.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the server cannot serialise the result object.
Make sure there is no exceptions on serialisation.